# show corresponding text fields on clicking radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I have two radio buttons "yes" and "no", on clicking "yes" two text fields should be shown and on clicking "no" another input text field should be generated. Previous input fields should be hidden, how to achieve this in HTML?

```html
    <input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="Radiobutton1" onclick="javascript:radioWithText('yes')" checked="checked" />Yes

    <input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="Radiobutton2" onclick="javascript:radioWithText('no')" />No

    <div id="Incident ID" style="display:visible;">
        <br>Incident ID :<input type="Text" name="Incident ID"/></br>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Description" style="display:visible;">
         <br>Description :<input type="Text" name="Description"/></br>
    </div>    

    <div id=" Ref" style="display:visible;">
        <br>Ref :<input type="Text" name="Ref"/></br>
    </div>
     

    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
     function radioWithText(d) {
      if(d =='yes'){
       document.getElementById('Incident ID').style.display = "visible";
       document.getElementById('Description').style.display = "visible";
       } else  (d == 'no') {
       document.getElementById('Ref').style.display = "visible";
      }
  }
    </script>
```

What I need to change here to get the desired output? I'm getting all the input fields for both the radio buttons.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please supply the code that you are working with along with what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please don't post your code as a comment. Go back and edit your question and include the code (formatted) there.

Comment: yes thank you, now code is added in question

Comment: Thank you for supplying your code. The first thing to do is to note that executing this code results in a syntax error. Your `else` should be `else if` when you are supplying a condition to be checked. In your case however, if `d` doesn't equal `yes`, you really don't need to explicitly check for `no`, so you can remove `(d == 'no')`.

Comment: yes i removed that condition

Comment: still all the text boxes where shown for both the radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You had a large amount of typos and were not really setting up your code correctly. See the inline comments below for details:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your page title here</title>
  <style>
    /* This CSS class is applied, by default to all the labels and
       textboxes. The JavaScript just adds or removes it as needed. */
    .hidden { display:none; }
    
    /* Give each element that uses this class a one line top and bottom margin to
       separate it from other elements. */
    .row { margin: 1em 0; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Radio Buttons should have a value that describes the meaning of the button.
       Here, yes and no will do it. Also, don't use inline HTML event attributes, such
       as "onclick", ever. It's extremely outdated, can lead to bugs and duplicated
       code and doesn't follow modern best-practices. Instead do your event handling
       in JavaScript. -->
  <input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="yes" checked="checked">Yes
  <input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="no">No

  <!-- All of the following is hidden by default. -->
  <!-- Don't include spaces in element ID's -->
  <div id="IncidentID" class="hidden row">
    <!-- Don't use break tags for arbitrary line feeds. They are for breaking content 
         at a logical flow. Use CSS for layout. Also, don't use "/" at the end of 
         an opening tag as this syntax isn't needed and can cuase you to use it in
         places where you shouldn't. You had </br> for example, which is incorrect. -->
    Incident ID :<input type="Text" name="Incident ID">
  </div>

  <div id="Description" class="hidden row">
    Description :<input type="Text" name="Description">
  </div>  

  <div id="Ref" class="hidden row">
    Ref :<input type="Text" name="Ref row">
  </div>
     
  <!-- no need for 'type="text/javascript"' and 'language=javascript' -->
  <script>

    // Get all the radio buttons and put them into an array
    var radioButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']"));
     
    // Loop through the array of radio buttons
    radioButtons.forEach(function(btn){
      // Set up a click event handling function for each button
      btn.addEventListener("click", radioWithText);
    });
    
    // No need to pass any data to this function because the button that triggers it
    // ("this" in the code below) can just look at its own HTML value to know what the
    // meaning of the button is.
   function radioWithText() {
      // Get references to the elements the function needs to work with.
      var incident = document.getElementById('IncidentID');
      var description = document.getElementById('Description');
      var ref = document.getElementById('Ref');
        
     if(this.value ==='yes'){
        // Instead of gettting/setting inline styles with the style property, just add
        // or remove pre-made CSS classes. Since all the textboxes and labels start out
        // with the CSS "hidden" class applied to them, it's just a matter of adding that
        // class or removing it as necessary.
       incident.classList.remove("hidden");
       description.classList.remove("hidden");
        ref.classList.add("hidden");
     } else {
        incident.classList.add("hidden");
       description.classList.add("hidden");
       ref.classList.remove("hidden");
     }
   }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```